# Async socket reading

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

So I've started to muck around with sockets and asynchronously reading from them.

First question is what is the difference between this:

`socket.BeginReceive(readResult.Buffer, 0, SocketReadResult.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), readResult);`

and

`socket.BeginReceive(readResult.Buffer, 0, SocketReadResult.BufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, readResult);`

Also, given this as my callback function, why did the example I read have a try/catch around the whole thing, surely you only need a try/catch around the `socket.EndReceive()` call?

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        var readResult = (SocketReadResult)ar.AsyncState;
        var socket = readResult.Socket;
        int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            readResult.Text.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readResult.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            socket.BeginReceive(readResult.Buffer, 0, SocketReadResult.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), readResult);
        }
        else
        {
            var newRead = new SocketReadResult(socket);

            socket.BeginReceive(readResult.Buffer, 0, SocketReadResult.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), newRead);

            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (readResult.Text.Length > 1) ((IMessageSender)this).RouteMessage(this, new MessageString(readResult.Text.ToString()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: manage this exception.
    }
}

public struct SocketReadResult
{
    StringBuilder Text;
    Socket Socket;
    byte[] Buffer;

    public const int BufferSize = 1024;

    public SocketReadResult(Socket s)
    {
        Socket = s;
        Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        Text = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Last of all, should you wish to gracefully close the listener after you have called `socket.BeginReceive()`, what functions do you call and how is it managed?

Comment: As to why the try/catch is around the whole method, ReadCallBack will be performed asynchronously possibly on another thread or the threadpool. If an exception were to be thrown it would not propagate back to the main thread as you would expect and would crash your process (eventually). For that reason you always need to have anything that could run on a separate thread completely wrapped in try/catch as that is your last chance to gracefully handle the error.

Comment: The different signatures and the exception handling are really two separate questions.  You shouldn't ask both in the same question.  Pick one or the other, and edit the other out (and post it as a new question if needed).

Comment: i dont get the point why are you trying to read even when bytesRead == 0 in else part?

Comment: @appdeveloper to handle the last read?

Comment: if no data is received then why use Socket.BeginReceive? that is simply end of data available

Comment: @AppDeveloper Because there is no data available, I ham setting up a new callback with a new struct for the next read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.BeginReceive(readResult.Buffer, 0, SocketReadResult.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), readResult);`

and

`socket.BeginReceive(readResult.Buffer, 0, SocketReadResult.BufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, readResult);`

both are the same thing, its same thing as

```
        //both are the same thing
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

Comment: The key point here is that the compiler will infer the type of the delegate and transform the second snippet into the first on your behalf.

Answer (score 2):

**a)** They are equal. Compiler will generate the same code for you

**b)** How about writing some extension methods for async calls and handle the exceptions as if they were sync calls without blocking the caller?

```
try
{
    await socket.ConnectTaskAsync("www.google.com", 80);

    await socket.SendTaskAsync(bytesToSend);

    byte[] buf = new byte[0x8000];
    var bytesRead = await socket.ReceiveTaskAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

---

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static Task ConnectTaskAsync(this Socket socket, string host, int port)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                     socket.BeginConnect(host, port, null, null),
                     socket.EndConnect);
    }

    public static Task<int> ReceiveTaskAsync(this Socket socket, 
                                            byte[] buffer, 
                                            int offset, 
                                            int count)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
           socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None, null, socket),
           socket.EndReceive);
    }


    public static Task SendTaskAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
              socket.BeginSend(buffer,0,buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None, null, socket),
              socket.EndSend);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two calls is negligible and you can consider them equivalent. The second call will help the compiler do type inferencing for you, but that won't be very noticeable outside IntelliSense and auto-completion of code. I personally use the first format since it is more concise.

As for why the `try/catch` is more than just the `Socket.EndReceive()` call mostly has to do with the scope of other local variables.

Consider this:

```
var state = result.AsyncState as SocketStateObject;
var socket = state.Socket;

try
{
  var numberOfBytesRead = socket.EndReceive(result);
}
catch(SocketException ex)
{
  // Handle the exception here.
}

// numberOfBytesRead is not accessible out here!

try
{
  if(socket.Connected)
    socket.BeginReceive(...); // Receive again!
}
catch(SocketException ex)
{
  // Handle the exception here too.
}
```

As you can see here, there are a couple reasons why one, larger `try/catch` is preferable to two separate, smaller ones.

First off, local variables are only available within the scope of the `try`. You could solve that by defining it higher outside the `try/catch` block.

Secondly, and probably more importantly, has to do with reducing redundancy. Since you are more than likely going to call `Socket.BeginReceive()` again in your callback, it makes sense to put it under the same `try/catch`. Otherwise, you'd have to handle your potential `SocketException` in two places instead of just one.

As for closing a `Socket` gracefully, you can use the `Socket.Close()` method. Typically sockets are never reused so you can pass `false` for that. However, it is preferable to call `Socket.Dispose()` as well, after the `Socket.Close()` call. If you are holding the listener socket as a member variable of your class, make sure you implement the `IDisposable` interface and properly dispose of your socket.

Comment: It's it considered bad form to surround code that doesn't throw an error in a try catch?

Comment: In general, you should program to avoid throwing and catching exceptions as much as possible. `try/catch` blocks are nice but do come at a performance cost, even if the exception is never thrown. Caught exceptions only incur an even higher penalty. For example, you should use `TryParse()` that does not throw exceptions versus `Parse()` which will (ex: `int.TryParse()`). However, sometimes exceptions are unavoidable in cases like `Sockets` where network errors are out of your control no matter how good your code may be. In these cases, you should use `try/catch`.